# how to turn readlines into a string... perhaps?

Tags: python

I think my largest problem is I don't know how to ask the question of what it is exactly that I am looking for.

I stole most the code from a flashcard program from http://www.tuxradar.com/content/code-project-build-flash-card-app and modified it a bit to suit my own needs.  However, when I get the answer correct it still says I've gotten it wrong.
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import random
import time

file1 = open('/root/first.txt', 'w')
file2 = open('/root/second.txt', 'w')

file1.writelines('1\n2\n3\n4\n5')
file2.writelines('0,2\n1,3\n2,4\n3,5\n4,6')

time.sleep(1)

file1.close
file2.close

time.sleep(1)

file1 = open('/root/first.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('/root/second.txt', 'r')

count = 0
score = 0
tries = int(raw_input('How many tries?'))
start_time = time.time()

f1content = file1.readlines()
f2content = file2.readlines()

try:
    while count < tries:
        os.system('clear')

        wordnum = random.randint(0, len(f1content)-1)
        correct = str(f2content[wordnum])

        print 'Number:', f1content[wordnum], ''

        answer = input('\nSurrounding numbers?')

        if answer == correct:
            raw_input('\nCorrect! Hit enter...')
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print '\nNope, It\'s', correct
            raw_input('Hit enter to try a new one...')

        count = count + 1

except SyntaxError:
    print 'you must enter a value, starting over'
    os.system('./flash.py')

finally:
    file1.close
    file2.close
    os.system('rm /root/first.txt')
    os.system('rm /root/second.txt')

stop_time = time.time() - start_time
print '\nIt took you', stop_time / 60, 'minutes to get', score, 'out of', count, 'correct'
```

I postulate that my problem lies in Line 35 where I define correct as

```
correct = str(f2content[wordnum])
```

The reason I think this is because if it gives me `1` and I know that the correct answer is `0,2` and I type that in, it say's nope, it's `0,2`.  This suggests that in plain text it is the exact same to the human eye but that the computer is reading it as something different. I tried to make it a string because of this and making it an integer causes an error. I'm really stuck and am sure it's something so simple but I am just not seeing it.  Any help would be appreciated.  Even if it is just a point in the right direction of where I can find the answer.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Please look at http://sscce.org/

Comment: Without knowing what's in /root/first.txt and /root/second.txt, it's pretty hard to debug. But no matter what, I can tell you that `f2content[wordnum]` will already be a string—readlines just returns a list of strings—so calling `str` on it won't do anything at all.

Comment: The first step toward debugging this is to add a line like `print repr(answer), repr(correct)` right before the comparison. That way it should be obvious if you're reading off by one, or have whitespace-related problems, or something else entirely, and you can ask a much better question, like "How do I get rid of the extra newline I get back from the `raw_input`?" or "Why is `f1content[35]` giving me the value I thought should be in `f1content[34]`?" than just a vague "Why doesn't this work"? (That's not a substitute for SSCCE, but something else to do to help.)

Comment: In the new version, do you really mean `file1.writelines('1\n2\n3\n4\n5')` rather than `file1.write('1\n2\n3\n4\n5')` or `file1.writelines(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])`? I'm not sure what the former does, but I'll bet it's nothing good.

Comment: Also, your `file#.close` are missing parens: `file#.close()`.

Comment: And your indentation is wrong; presumably everything inside the `try:` should also be inside the `while`, but it won't run at all as-is.

Comment: Marcin - The code simply compares the lines of two different files allowing you to type in the expected answer and it tells you correct or not.  Pillmuncher - 100% right. thank you.  Abarnert - This is my first attempt on getting help through this site so I made more than a few mistakes while trying to indent it for upload.  Copy and paste wouldn't work.  Thank you for your evaluation and the input below. It is much appreciated.

Comment: Glad you got the answer. But for future reference, if you haven't read the sscce.org link yet, you should; you'll get faster and better (and sometimes friendlier) help that way. Also, look over a few other questions on the site and see what kind of questions get upvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I fixed all the problems given in the comments above.

Instead of `writeline`, use `write`:

```
file1.write('1\n2\n3\n4\n5')
file2.write('0,2\n1,3\n2,4\n3,5\n4,6')
```

Add the parentheses to `close`:

```
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Indent everything between the `while` and the end of the `try`.

Debug by adding the following before the comparison:

```
print repr(answer), repr(correct)
```

Also, I went through and changed all the `/root/first.txt`, etc. into just `first.txt`, so it'll work on a system that doesn't have a writable directory named `/root` (which most systems won't).

So, when I run it, I see this:

```
Number: 4


Surrounding numbers?3,5
(3, 5) '3,5\n'

Nope, It's 3,5

Hit enter to try a new one...
```

So clearly, `answer` is the tuple `(3, 5)` rather than the string `3,5`, and `correct` is the string `3,5\n` rather than the string `3,5`.

If you read [the documentation for input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input), it should be clear why `answer` is wrong. It's trying to interpret my `3,5` as a Python expression, and it's a perfectly valid way to write the tuple `(3, 5)`, so that's why I get. To fix that, you want to use `raw_input`.

If you read [the documentation for readlines](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines), it should be clear why each line has a newline at the end. There are a number of ways around this.

Having fixed that, it still fails at the end, because it never creates the files `table.txt` and `pocket.txt` that it tries to delete. Whatever you were trying to do there, you appear to have missed something. I just commented out those lines.

While you're at it, I'd change the `open`/`readlines`/`close` into a more modern Python pattern, using `with` and treating the file as just a string iterator. And hardcoding paths like `/root/first.txt` isn't a very good idea.

Anyway, I don't want to give the exact changes needed, because this feels like homework, but I think the above is enough information for you to fix it yourself, and hopefully learn a little about how to debug the next problem on your own. If you still have problems, ask away.

Comment: The Debug info is very helpful.  Thank you.  The indentations are messed up on the example, I see that now.  Sorry.  table.txt and pocket.txt don't exist.  They should have been first.txt and second.txt respectively.  I have spent less than a week coding and have no real resources other than the python docs which I don't always understand.  I thank you so much for your direction and will attempt to figure out the rest on my own.  Though I may be back to clarify.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I got it.  raw_input was the ticket to get answer to string instead of tuple.  And I had to change from  f2content = file2.readlines() to f2content = file2.read().splitlines() to get correct to read without the \n.  Thanks again!!

Comment: Great! I realize the tutorial built into the Python documentation isn't that great. Maybe check out http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers or http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers as appropriate for links to others.